# Problem with simulation of a N-MOSFET in PSpice

Tags: mosfet, simulation, pspice, powermosfet

Im trying to make a simulation based on a DC sweep with this circuit:

[image]

At the moment of simulation I receive this warning:

```
WARNING:  [NET0093]
No PSpiceTemplate for M4, ignoring
```

It does not plot any data or traces. The simulation runs with the given parameters, but how can the warning be corrected?

The model is from the EVAL.lib for SPICE. The IRF150 is an N-channel MOSFET.

Comment: I never liked pspice.   Falstad is more fun. http://tinyurl.com/y4a3wz3r

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75, unfortunately this have to done in pspice, but thanks for the tip!

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/y4w7b4y6  or get LTSpice XVII

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I don't understand the model provided in the eval.lib under the pspice directory is not working, so I take these steps to solve it

- Look for another version of the eval.lib that found [here](http://noel.feld.cvut.cz/vyu/eos/lib/eval.lib)
- Open it with the model editor
- Without modifying exported via File> Export to Capture Part Library to create the .lib and .olb objects
- If you received a message of 0 errors then its ok.
- Inside your project you have to add to the path of work, so you have to make right click in the “Library” folder, then add file, look for the .lib you just make.
- In the dialog of selecting file type you choose "Schematic library" and then ok
- Left click the .LIB file you just added and Ctrl+C.
- Left click the "Model Libraries” folder and the Ctrl+V
- The lib model must be in both the Library and Model library folders

  That´s it, after that it run well.